# cannot pass dos path and to preserve it in cygwin command line

Tags: windows, cygwin, cygpath

I have problems passign windows path to an non-Cygwin application in Cygwin

```
app 'd:\path\file'
```

That application gives an error of `/d:/path/file does not exist`.

How stop Cygwin with modifying the input argument in this case?

It prepends / to the path.

**It does not prepend, it just looks so by the misleading error message.**

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the path by enclosing in quotes e.g. `notepad "c:\a.txt"`.  You also might need to protect the backslash (`\`) characters in the path by doubling them (`notepad "c:\\a.txt"`).

Comment: What does notepad say for these two invocations from cygwin: `notepad c:\\a.txt` and `notepad "c:\\a.txt"`?  Assuming there is no a.txt in the root directory of the C drive, it should pop up a dialog displaying the path as it (notepad) sees it.  You could experiment with that a bit.

Comment: yes, this works. It looks like the problem is application specific

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? I don't see that with my cygwin. You may have better luck with

```
app "$(cygpath -ma <cygwin-path<)"
```

My environment:

```
$ cygcheck -c bash cygwin
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
bash                 4.1.10-4       OK
cygwin               1.7.9-1        OK
$ cat check.bat
@echo %1%
$ ./check.bat 'c:\cygwin\tmp\t'
c:\cygwin\tmp\t
```